# Approximating Dirac Delta Function as Point Load

Tags: numerical-integration

For a point load on a simply supported beam, this is the corresponding shear force, bending moment, slope and displacement curve that i obtained.
[image]

Now i want to approximate this point load using a Dirac Delta function **7.95775*10^-6/(6.25*10^-10 + x^2)**. How can I numerically integrate it from bounds -10 to 10, and plot it so that i get shear force, bending moment, slope and displacement graph similar to one i obtained from point load?

[image]

Comment: `DiracDelta` isn't a numerical function. You'll have to use something with a finite width.

Comment: The function **7.95775*10^-6/(6.25*10^-10 + x^2)** is used as an approximate for numerical work of Dirac Delta

Comment: What's wrong with `NIntegrate`?

Comment: I did NIintegrate it and got a set of values by creating a table. How can i NIntegrate the VALUES again and then plot it?

Comment: Perhaps you want `NDsolve`. Unless you show us what you've tried, it's difficult to understand what your problem is.

Comment: Gave a screenshot

Comment: Unreadable. Please post code as code.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you don't use the actual delta fn.  Mma makes it really easy.

Start with a simply supported beam with a point load `pa` at `x = a`, and the support loads `p0` at `x = 0` and `pL` at `x = L`.  Solve for the support loads:
Forces sum to 0.

```
eq1 = p0 + pL - pa == 0;
```

The torque about `x = 0`

```
eq2 = a pa - L pL == 0;

psol = Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {p0, pL}] // Flatten;

p0 = p0 /. psol;
pL = pL/.psol;
```

Use DiracDelta to get an expression for the loads.

```
p[x_] = p0 DiracDelta[x] - pa DiracDelta[x - a] + pL DiracDelta[x - L]
```

For a simply supported beam, the displacements and moments at each end are 0, and the ode for the displacement v is

```
ode = EI v''''[x] == p[x];
bc = {v[0] == 0, v[L] == 0, v''[0] == 0, v''[L] == 0};

DSolve[{ode, bc}, v[x], x] // Flatten // Simplify;

v[x_] = v[x] /. %;
```

Slope

```
slope[x_] = v'[x] // Simplify
```

Moment

```
M[x_] = EI v''[x]
```

Shear

```
V[x_] = -EI v'''[x]
```

Plug in numbers for plotting.  I don't know what yours were.

```
L = 20;
pa = .1;
a = 15;
EI = 1000;

Plot[v[x], {x, 0, L}, PlotLabel -> "Displacement"]
```

[image]

```
Plot[slope[x]/\[Degree], {x, 0, L}, PlotLabel -> "Slope (degree)"]
```

[image]

```
Plot[M[x], {x, 0, L}, PlotLabel -> "Moment"]
```

[image]

```
Plot[V[x], {x, 0, L}, PlotLabel -> "Shear", Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you want to do but we can approximate the point load at x = 10 by:

```
   p[x_] = 7.95775*10^-6/(6.25*10^-10 + x^2) /. x -> 10 - x
```

The differential equation relating the bending moment to the point load is:

```
   eq1 = D[M[x], {x, 2}] == p[x]
```

We can use NDSolve to solve for the bending moment:

```
  soln1 = NDSolve[{eq1, M[0] == 0, M[20] == 0}, M, {x, 0, 20}]
```

We can now plot the bending moment:

```
  Plot[-M[x] /. soln1[[1]], {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 6}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "M[x]"}, PlotLabel -> "Bending moment", GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True]
```

The shear force is the derivative of the bending moment:

```
  V[x_] = -D[M[x] /. soln1[[1]], {x, 1}]
```

Similarly we plot the shear force diagram:

```
 Plot[V[x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {-0.75, 0.75}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "V[x]"}, PlotLabel -> "Shear force", GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True]
```